# Google Chart Throwing Different Undefined Errors

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, undefined

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qCW7D/).

I set up a simple google charts example on my site that has been working fine for several weeks. All of a sudden it no longer works. I've checked the git history and I haven't touched the code that handles it. In chrome I receive the following error for where the graph should be `Cannot read property 'jI' of undefined`. On firefox I receive `a is undefined`. Neither browsers produce errors on the console.

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("visualization", "1", {
            packages: ["corechart"]
        });
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                ['Name',  'Amount in Dollars'],
                ['ALLOCATED', 5000],
                ['PAID-TO-DATE', 5000]]);

            var ticks = [0,0];

            var options = {
                width: 230,
                height: 400,
                fontName: 'Source Sans Pro',
                // If no background color is provided, defaults to white
                backgroundColor: undefined,
                hAxis:   { baselineColor:  'white'},
                vAxis:   { 
                  baselineColor:  'white',
                  gridlines:   { color:  'black', count:  2 },
                  ticks:  ticks
                },
                legend:   { position:  "none" }
            };

            var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
```

My question is, what's wrong and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a couple of syntax errors in your DataTable construction on this line:

```
['PAID-TO-DATE', 5000])]]);
```

there is no pairing for the first `)` and third `]`.  It should be:

```
['PAID-TO-DATE', 5000]]);
```

Then, in your chart options, you specify the `vAxis.ticks` option with a `ticks` variable, but `ticks` is `undefined`.

If you fix these, the chart should draw: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/4UaA6/

Comment: My apologizes. Both of those errors shouldn't be there. The error is still appearing and I'm stumped.

Comment: Furthermore, when I directly plugged the code from the jsfiddle into my app I received the error `Cannot read property 'Po' of undefined` on where the column chart should be.

Comment: Are you using any other javascript frameworks or libraries, or have any other custom scripts?  Some libraries (Prototype.js in particular) modify base javascript object prototypes in ways that make them incompatible with the Visualization API.

Comment: I'm not using Prototype. However I am using jquery and angularjs. Let me reiterate that this was working fine before. The code that dealt with the graph was untouched. No changes have been made to cause it to break. I have to think it's something outside the code I presented you.

Comment: I suggest doing some experimentation to build an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); if I can duplicate the issue, it will be much easier for me to help you.